# Как оформить алгоритм (последовательность) выполняемых действий на Activity? - Программирование Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk

Здравствуйте, у меня есть некоторое `Activity` посредством которого должна выполняться некоторая совокупность вычислительных операций и эти действия должны выполняться строго последовательно, под определённым алгоритмом.

Данный алгоритм должен выполняться следующий образом:

- Инициализация действия `RadioGroup`
- Выбор значений переменных для выбранного действия `ListView`
- Вывод ответа на следующий `Activity(Toast)`

Сейчас при выполнении алгоритма выводится `0.0`

Т.к., при выполнении 1-го действия, игнорируется работа 2-го действия алгоритма, впоследствии выводится `0.0`

Однако, если выполнить сначала 2-ое действие, а потом 1-ое, приложение выводит правильный ответ.

Думаю, что ошибка в обработчике действия `RadioGroup`, но не знаю как его поправить.
Как можно исправить ошибку?
Заранее спасибо, за любой дельный совет!)

**Код MessageActivity1:**

```
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.RadioButton;
 import android.widget.RadioGroup;
 import android.widget.Spinner;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import static app.analysis.mai.MatrixMessageActiviry123.w0;


 public class MessageActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView celzadach, poyas4, poyas5, poyas6;
RadioGroup rgroup;
RadioButton sravnenkr1, sravnenkr2, sravnenkr3;  //Объявление элементов MessageActivity1
ListView spisok1;
Spinner spn2;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;
String prioritet[] = {"9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"};
double znachn1;  // Объявление переменных
Button sootnesen1;
static double d, b;
boolean block;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message1);

    celzadach = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.celzadach);
    Intent intent5 = getIntent();
    String message1 = intent5.getStringExtra("message1"); //Перенос введенного сообщения из RememderEditText Activity1 в TextView MessageActivity1
    celzadach.setText(message1);

    poyas4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poyas4);
    poyas4.setText("Определение важности критериев сравнения относительно заявленной цели:");

    poyas5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poyas5);
    poyas5.setText("Какой из сравниваемых критериев более предпочтительный?");

    poyas6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poyas6);
    poyas6.setText("Предпочтительней на сколько?");

    sravnenkr1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.sravnenkr1);
    Intent intent6 = getIntent();
    String message2 = intent6.getStringExtra("message2"); //Перенос введенного сообщения из RememderEditText Activity1 в RadioButton MessageActivity1
    sravnenkr1.setText(message2);

    sravnenkr2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.sravnenkr2);
    Intent intent7 = getIntent();
    String message3 = intent7.getStringExtra("message3"); //Перенос введенного сообщения из RememderEditText Activity1 в RadioButton MessageActivity1
    sravnenkr2.setText(message3);

    sravnenkr3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.sravnenkr3);
    sravnenkr3.setText("Сравниваемые критерии одинаково важны");

    rgroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup1);
    rgroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes int q) { //Обработчик событий нажатия на RadioButton, по выбору действия
            d = 1;
            b = 1;
            if (q == sravnenkr1.getId()) { //Обработка нажатия 1-го RadioButton c присвоением переменной d и b значений
                d = znachn1;
                b = 1 / d;
            }
            else if (q == sravnenkr2.getId()) { //Обработка нажатия 2-го RadioButton c присвоением переменной d и b значений
    b = znachn1;
    d = 1 / b;
}
}
});//Возможная ошибка кроется тут, т.к. дефакто присваиваемая тут переменная znachn1=0.0, уже после её присваивания игнорируется работа другого обработчика

    spisok1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.spisokPrioritet);
    adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, prioritet);
    spisok1.setAdapter(adapter2);
    spisok1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position2, long id) { //Обработчик событий нажатия на RadioButton, по выбору значения переменной znachn1 по id
            znachn1 = (id < 9) ? 9 - id : 0; //Обработка нажатия на элементы списка, где согласно условию znachn1 = (ЕСЛИ ID < 9) ТО 9 - ID ИНАЧЕ 0
        }
    });

    sootnesen1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sootnesen1);
    sootnesen1.setText("Далее");
    sootnesen1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent8 = new Intent(MessageActivity1.this, MessageActivity2.class);
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"w0="+w0, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); // Вывод значения импортированной ранее переменной w0, посредством произведённого вычисления, через Toast на MessageActivity2 по нажатию на Button
            toast1.show();
            startActivity(intent8);
        }

    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно, вы же получаете значение `znachn1` во втором обработчике, а потом используете в первом. Вам нужно инициализировать `znachn1` значением по умолчанию еще до обработчика (видимо соответствующим первому пункту списка).

Целиком код может выглядеть как то так (некоторые ID виджетов изменены, так как тестировал у себя в проекте):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Integer prioritet[] = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
    double znachn1, b, d;
    int checkedRadioButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        final TextView celzadach = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.celzadach);
        final RadioButton radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        final RadioButton radioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        final RadioGroup rgroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        String message1 = intent.getStringExtra("message1");
        celzadach.setText(message1);
        String message2 = intent.getStringExtra("message2");
        radioButton1.setText(message2);
        String message3 = intent.getStringExtra("message3");
        radioButton2.setText(message3);

        rgroup.check(R.id.radioButton1); // отмечаем первый чекбокс
        checkedRadioButton = R.id.radioButton1;
        rgroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checked) {
                switch (checked) {
                    case R.id.radioButton1:
                        checkedRadioButton = R.id.radioButton1;
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioButton2:
                        checkedRadioButton = R.id.radioButton2;
                        break;
                }
                calculate();
            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, prioritet);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        znachn1 =(Integer) spinner.getSelectedItem(); // получаем значение при начальной позиции в списке
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                znachn1 = (Integer) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                calculate();
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void calculate() {
        if (checkedRadioButton == R.id.radioButton1){
            d = znachn1;
            b = 1 / d;
        }
        if (checkedRadioButton == R.id.radioButton2){
            b = znachn1;
            d = 1 / b;
        }
    }
}
```

При любом изменении в виджетах (радиобатонах или спиннере) значения переменных *znachn1*, *b*, *d* будет пересчитано (не знаю, что вы с ними дальше хотите делать). Значения для расчета znacn1 берутся из массива значений, а не вычисляются из позиции, что позволяет использовать произвольные числа

PS: замечания по коду:

Не нужно в коде присваивать виджетам статический текст (который не будет изменяться при работе приложения). Указывайте его в xml-разметке через атрибут *android:text*. Например для TextView (аналогично для всех других виджетов):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Статический текст"
/>
```

В реальном приложении вообще строго не рекомендуется хардкорить текст в код, а нужно выносить его в ресурсы @string

Получайте один раз интент и выбирайте из него все нужные значения

Не выводите переменные в поля класса без необходимости

Для выбора одного значения из списка правильнее использовать spinner, а не listview. В listview не очень интуитивно понятно, что именно выбрано, а "портянка" всех значений постоянно на экране не нужна и даже мешает

Давайте переменным осмысленные имена в соответствии с их назначением, а не spisok1, adapter2, message3

Comment: Про adapter2 и Intent очень интересно, а вот c переменной так и не сработало, если задать её как znachn1 = 9 еще до обработчика, то действуя по описанному алгоритму выводится всегда один и тот же ответ, правильный только для 9.
Касательно spinner, вот именно как и сейчас, при работе с ним всегда выбиралась 9, при работе по алгоритму, т.е. при переходе на Activity spinner c ходу выбирал первое значение выпадающего списка..

Comment: очень странно .. В обработчике клика значение znachn1 меняется при нажатии на другие пункты?

Comment: нет, пункты меняются только, если сначала инициализировать znachn1 через ListView, а потом выбрать действие, т.е. как и до этого..
по-другому пункты не меняются

Comment: тогда проблема в обработчике кликов, хотя я не понял, как так может быть. Вы описываете какие то невероятные вещи ..

Comment: не совсем понятно, почему вы используете тип double для целочисленного значения и параметр id при кликах в ArrayAdapter (он не возвращает ID, значение этого параметра равно позиции в списке, если мне не изменяет память)

Comment: вроде тип double наоборот к месту, там все переменные используются под типом double, а благодаря параметру id я смог несколько облегчить код, т.к. до этого, собственно, позиция задавалась через switch..

Comment: я попробовал задать переменную через String, т.е. String znachn1 = " ".
Однако, при проверке инициализации действия (RadioGroup) приложение останавливает свою работу..

Comment: Но вот у меня ещё идея, а если обработчик Listview перенести выше обработчика RadioGroup, а саму переменную znachn1 к приравнять условию обработки нажатию списка, т.е. выбранному id.
Только в таком случае  оболочка ругается на переменную q в обработчиках нажатия RadioButtoms и на сам id в условии обработчика Listview, к которому приравниваем znachn1.

Comment: колбэки срабатывают по событию (нажатию на пункт списка в данном случае), а не чем выше в коде, тем раньше. то есть куда вы нк перенесете обработчик, выполнятся его код будет только когда нажмут на пункт в списке.

Comment: перенос кода я в данном случае сделал из-за скобки, но возможно ли приравнять znachn1 к условию обработчика списка, по факту ведь именно там прописана обработка нажатия.

Comment: Я учту ваши замечания по коду)

Answer (score 0):

```
znachn1 = Double.parseDouble(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

Я смог решить проблему, при помощи приравнивания переменной 'znachn1' к условию обработки нажатию списка, т.е. выбранному id. Алгоритм выполняется, всё правильно считается. Кому интересно полученный код имеет следующий вид:

```
    spisok1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.spisokPrioritet);
    adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, prioritet);
    spisok1.setAdapter(adapter2);

    rgroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup1);
    rgroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes final int q) {
            d = 1;
            b = 1;
            spisok1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position2, long id) {
                    znachn1 = String.valueOf((adapter2.getItemId(0) < 9) ? 9 - id : 0);

                    if (q == sravnenkr1.getId()) {
                        d = Double.valueOf(znachn1);
                        b = 1 / d;
                    }
                    else if (q == sravnenkr2.getId()) {
                        b = Double.valueOf(znachn1);
                        d = 1 / b;
                    }
                }
            });

            sootnesen1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent8 = new Intent(MessageActivity1.this, MessageActivity2.class);
                    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "w0=" + w0, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast1.show();
                    startActivity(intent8);
                }

            });


        }
    });
```

Comment: Хорошо, что работает и это конечно ваша программа и вы можете писать ее, как считаете нужным, но "вешать" обработчик внутри другого обработчика за гранью добра уже, как и получать через методы значения, которые явно переданы через параметр. Что будет, если сначала нажать на список?

Comment: Вас чем о не устраивает предложенное мной решение, что вы придумываете такие, мягко говоря, странные приемы? оно корректно работает, учитывает все возможные варианты действий пользователя и при этом не попирает принципы ООП программирования, но .. ?

Comment: Я ничего не имею против вашего решения, просто когда я обнаружил такой выход из проблемы и собственно выкладывал его здесь, я просто не увидел ваше решение, и я не считаю плохим, или не верным, напротив. Начиная с того, что вы построили работу алгоритм вокруг массива значений, что я не смог сделать, поэтому вывел условие обработчика, которое для верной работы пришлось вставить в другой обработчик - это мой косяк..
Я вижу ваше решение более умным, моё не более чем костыль..

Comment: Сейчас в обработчике действия я добавил ещё одно действие для 3 RadioButton, при котором переменные b=1,d=1.. При обработке списка сейчас выводится, сообщение что данных нет..

Comment: Кстати, в замечаниях вы написали, что стоит убрать код связанный со статическим текстом,а уместно ли это, если на некоторых Activity подразумевается добавление большого текста, я только поэтому его так оформил.

Comment: Как [работать со строковыми ресурсами](https://habrahabr.ru/post/133503/) в Android - создаете файл strings.xml, куда пишите все тексты любого размера. В xml-разметке ссылаетесь на эти тексты как `android:text="@string/someText"`. мое решение не более умное, просто оно правильное с точки зрения ООП.